# Python Chrome Driver Click Reader View on Safari Web Browser

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, screen-scraping

How do I click "Reader View" in Safari browser when scraping websites?

URL: https://www.w3resource.com/java-exercises/collection/index.php

I need a python script to click reader view then copy all contents to a text file.

Please see a snippet of my current code:

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/local/bin/chromedriver', options=options)
url = "https://www.w3resource.com/java-exercises/collection/index.php"
# TODO: Click Reader View.
# Copy all text on Reader View to a string variable.
# Paste string to a text file.
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Could you send the shortcut to the page where Reader View is enabled? I haven't tried the code below, but hopefully it can help.

```
reader_view = Keys.chord(Keys.SHIFT, Keys.COMMAND, "r");
driver.findElement(By.Xpath("//something")).sendKeys(selectAll);
```

Comment: Thanks for the code snippet. Reader View is enabled using the Safari Browser at https://www.w3resource.com/java-exercises/collection/index.php